# Vb.net changing colors of a picture

Tags: vb.net, graphics, colors

I am struggling with the following problem: I have a small picture with is painted in red. This color must be changed to another color (users'choice). I used msdn and some googling did the following:

```
    Private Function GetPicture(Iterator As Integer, tempfile As String) As String
        Dim Rstring = ""

        If Colors.Count = 0 OrElse Iterator >= Colors.Count Then
            Rstring = tempfile
        Else
            Dim NewPicture = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetTempFileName()
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(tempfile, NewPicture, True)
            Dim mypict = New Bitmap(NewPicture)

            Dim ColorList As New List(Of Color)

            For x = 0 To mypict.Width - 1
                For y = 0 To mypict.Height - 1
                    Dim mypixel = mypict.GetPixel(x, y)

                    If ColorList.Contains(mypixel) = False Then
                        ColorList.Add(mypixel)
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            Dim NewColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255)
            Dim ListOfColorMaps As New List(Of ColorMap)
            For Each elem In ColorList
                Dim newcolormap = New ColorMap
                newcolormap.OldColor = elem
                newcolormap.NewColor = NewColor
                ListOfColorMaps.Add(newcolormap)
            Next

            Dim imageAttributes As New ImageAttributes()
            Dim width As Integer = mypict.Width
            Dim height As Integer = mypict.Height
            Dim colorMap As New ColorMap()


            'colorMap.OldColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0) ' opaque red
            'colorMap.NewColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255) ' opaque blue
            Dim remapTable As ColorMap() = ListOfColorMaps.ToArray
            imageAttributes.SetRemapTable(remapTable, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap)

            Dim tempBmp = New Bitmap(width, height)
            Dim g = Graphics.FromImage(tempBmp)
            g.DrawImage(tempBmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0, width, height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes)

            g.Save()
            g.Dispose()
            mypict.Dispose()

            Dim NewFileName = NewPicture.Remove(NewPicture.IndexOf("."c) - 1) & ".png"
            tempBmp.Save(NewFileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(NewPicture)

            tempBmp.Dispose()
            Rstring = NewPicture
        End If


        Return Rstring
```

The Code runs without exceptions, and it seems to find the desired colors but the saved tempbmp contains no picture. Does this happen because the code runs in a dll without graphic?

You can pretty much ignore the "IF" part - that has something to do with another usecase.

Greetings and sincere thanks
Christian Sauer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting no picture displayed because you are drawing an empty bitmap.

Your problem starts here:

```
Dim tempBmp = New Bitmap(width, height)
Dim g = Graphics.FromImage(tempBmp)
g.DrawImage(tempBmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0, width, height, _
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes)
```

- You create a new bitmap (probably with a white background).
- Then you create a new `Graphics` object from your empty bitmap.
- Then you draw the **empty bitmap** onto itself.

What you should be doing is drawing the `mypict` object (which is the bitmap whose colors you want to change). Thus your third line should be as follows:

```
g.DrawImage(mypict, New Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0, width, height, _
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes)
```

Since the Graphics object `g` is associated with `tempBmp` (which is empty prior to the DrawImage operation) drawing `mypict` will draw to it with your parameters.

One other recommendation is that you remove the `g.Save()` line. You save a graphics object when you plan to restore it later. Doing a `Graphics.Save()` does not save a picture. What really saves the changes you have made is the `tempBmp.Save()` line.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!
I am still confused why you need the tempbmp -  I would have guessed that you can create g from mypict and then draw it...

Comment: When you create a `Graphics` from a bitmap, anything you do with the object is drawn to the bitmap you created the `Graphics` object from. So if you want to draw to `tempBmp`, do `Graphics.FromImage(tempBmp)`; if you want to draw to `mypict`, do `Graphics.FromImage(mypict)`. Anything you draw with the `g` will appear on the image you created the graphics object from.